# jquery mobile and dynamic link with hashtag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have navigations which required a dynamic value. however, it didn't pass the value with hashtag along with the dynamic navigation.

```
<a class="img-icon-category" href="faqs.php?q=value&#faqs-overview" data-transition="slide"> &nbsp; </a>
```

i would like to know if this code is correct. i tried to follow the jquery mobile doc but im still confuse on how to configure it in the best way to avoid showing header navigation dropping in iphone while switching page.

Note: im not a programmer or mobile developer, im interested to learn this thing for my project. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

remove the **&** that is before the **#** in the [`href`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) attribute, you only need it if you are going to pass more values in the [querystring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

change

```
<a class="img-icon-category" href="faqs.php?q=value&#faqs-overview" data-transition="slide"> &nbsp; </a>
```

to

```
<a class="img-icon-category" href="faqs.php?q=value#faqs-overview" data-transition="slide"> &nbsp; </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve you may need to HTML or URL encode some of your characters.

This sends `value&#faqs-overview` as the parameter to the `q` variable:

```
<a class="img-icon-category" href="faqs.php?q=value%26%23faqs-overview" data-transition="slide"> &nbsp; </a>
```

Note that if you are sending multiple parameters then you need to HTML encode your `&` parameter separators as `&amp;` or use `;` separators instead.